# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, tuples, typeerror

I was trying to build a simple and rudimentary code to see how many days would last my glory on a game and then when i tried to run this python threw this error

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

I checked my version on python, because i was working on Visual Studio, and turned out that i was using 3.7.7, the latest, from what i know
Then i tried on python ide that had 3.4.4 and turned the same error
First i thought was the version of python, 3.7.7, which is unstale, but then i switched to my Kali Linux and tried again and nothing changed, and i finally tried a online compiler, GDB,for those who knows it, it have 3.4.4
I don t know what i did wrong, please let me know

```
glory=10445
days=0
while glory>=7500:
    glory*=0,99
    days+=1
print(days)
```

Comment: use dot instead of comma for floating point numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
glory*=0,99
```

It should be:

```
glory*=0.99
```

We use a dot `.` to separate decimals, not a comma `,` - a comma is used for separating elements in a list or a tuple, and that's what the error says.

Comment: To explain a little further: the comma is problematic because it creates a tuple.  After that assignment, `glory` stops being an `int` and starts being a `tuple`, which is why you get the `TypeError` when you compare it to an `int`.